# What would the basic gear for fly fishing be?

Tags: fly-fishing

If one were to get started fly fishing what gear would one need just to start with?

Of course, there is all sorts of gear and better gear, but what would the minimum gear to start with be?

Answer (score 4):

As I'm going through a minimalist phase of fishing right now, I suggest this as a functional minimum.

- License; Your location determines if this is actually needed.
- Rod
- Reel; Not absolutely necessary, but it helps manage the line.
- Fly Line
- Tippet/Leader; One length of mono is what I'm using now.
- Flies; I'm now using only muddler minnows and a grub pattern.  I usually bring 1 tied to the line and 1 each in my pocket.  Your choice will differ.
- Forceps; I may eliminate these if I can get a productive fly tied on a circle hook.
- A body of water with fish in it;  If there are no fish, then you are only casting, not fishing.

This is what I take to fish small lakes and ponds targeting pan fish and bass.

Answer (score 2):

The minimum gear would be,

- Fishing license.
- Fly fishing rod.
- Preloaded reel with both backing and leader.
- A small assortment of flies.
- Strike indicators for the wet flies.
- Dry fly floatant for the dry flies.
- [Hemostat](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/a/20504/8794) for tieing the flies to the line and releasing the fish.
- Fingernail clippers for trimming excess line.
- Polarized sunglasses to help with the glare.
- Shoes for walking in the stream (sandals, Crocs, waders etc).
- Hat
- Something to carry your gear in such as a vest of backpack.

As you do more fly fishing or your gear wears out you may find other gear that you need or that makes certain things easier but the above is really the minimum amount of gear needed to start.